# Vim-based alternative for Emacs tramp-mode

Tags: netrw, ssh, network

Disclaimer: this question was posted prior to [unix.se](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/606695/vim-based-alternative-for-emacs-tramp-mode) but, as recommended by a moderator, was reposted here.  The original question was not (yet) deleted since some good comments were posted there.

---

I'm currently using `neovim` as my IDE for writing and executing `GNU R`-code (using the [`Nvim-R` plugin](https://github.com/jalvesaq/Nvim-R), which serves as my REPL), which works great on my local machine. When having higher workloads or demands, I'm `ssh`-ing into a remote machine, installing my `nvim` plugins and running `nvim` as a "local" application on the server.

Recently I realized that `Emacs` has the ingenious `TRAMP` mode ([Transparent Remote Access, Multiple Protocols](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode)), which allows to not only open files remotely, but also execute commands on a remote machine. From what I understand this means that I could use `Emacs` as a REPL (e.g., using `ESS`), writing code using my local `Emacs`-instance, but executing it on a remote machine where I have `GNU R` installed (see also [ESS processes on remote computers](https://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html#ESS-processes-on-Remote-Computers)).

I'd be interested to know if something similar exists for `vim` or `neovim`. I'm aware that I can edit files remotely using

```
vim scp://USER@SERVER:PORT//absolute/path/to/file
```

or

```
vim
:e scp://USER@SERVER:PORT//absolute/path/to/file
```

but from what I understand this actually creates a temporary copy of the file on my local machine; when running my `Nvim-R`-REPL this opens the working directory locally on `/tmp/something`.

I thought about experimenting with [`vim-slime`](https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime), [`repl.nvim`](https://github.com/HiPhish/repl.nvim) or [`neoterm`](https://github.com/kassio/neoterm), but I'm unsure if I would be able to replicate an `Emacs`-like experience.

Any ideas? Has anybody achieved something similar?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: I’ve inlined the links with a bit of markdown, which you can use to format most things on Stack Exchange. I’m not aware of anything like this currently, but would love to be.

Comment: @b-ben-knoble: thanks a lot!

Comment: @d-ben-knoble: By the way: I wanted to add other tags (like I did at the original post: [emacs] [vim] [remote] [ssh] [r]) but wasn't able to do so since some of the tags don't (yet?) exist on vi.se.  If you think those tags would make more sense for someone searching for that question I'd be grateful for an update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still haven't found the perfect solution, but one that works for me reasonably well: by using [`vim-slime`](https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime) (which is written in only `vimscript`).

In my `config-file` (`~/.config/nvim/init.vim` or `~/.vimrc`), I'm using the following line(s):

```
let g:slime_target = "neovim"
"let g:slime_target = "vimterminal"
"let g:slime_target = "screen"
"let g:slime_target = "tmux"
```

Only one of them is needed.  The first line is used for `neovim`, but if I'm using `vim` I use the second one (uncommented).  In my workflow I'm `ssh`-ing into a remote machine, then open the file I want to use (e.g. my `script.R` or `list_of_commands.sh`), then create a `:vertical split` and subsequently open a `:terminal`, where I can then run e.g. my `GNU R`-interpreter or a `bash`.  If one prefers to use a terminal multiplexer, the new split can be created using either `screen` (with `Ctrl-a |` `Ctrl-a l` `Ctrl-a c`) or `tmux` (with `Ctrl-b %`) and have the appropriate line from above (uncommented) in the `config-file`.

When I then invoke the `:SlimeSend`-command (abbreviated with `Ctrl-c` `Ctrl-c`, so the same key-combination has to be pressed twice), the text I'm currently having my cursor on is selected to be send to the target (which, when the configuration is correct and your split is already present, is written in correctly by default).

That might not be as elegant as `TRAMP` in `Emacs`, but it works.  But if anyone has ideas for improvement, don't hesitate to suggest them!